# How to cherry-pick a range of commits but stop for amending?

Tags: git, range, git-commit, cherry-pick

- To pick a single commit: `git cherry-pick A`
- To pick a single commit, but stop for ammending: `git cherry-pick A -n`
- To pick a range of commits: `git cherry-pick A..B`

However, what do I do if I want to pick a range of commits, but amend each commit? This doesn't work:

```
git cherry-pick A..B -n
```

because it stops with all modified files from all commits staged together, so that if I amend and then commit, all changes will be merged into a single commit.

Comment: I suspect you can't do this with Git alone. What environment are we talking about here; Windows or something Unix-like?

Comment: Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After cherry-picking A..B, you could perform an interactive rebase

```
git rebase ORIG_HEAD -i
```

then select what you want to do from the regular interactive rebase commands:

```
Commands:
  p, pick = use commit
  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```